# Why does my query fail with AnalysisException?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark streaming. I am trying structured Spark streaming with local csv files. I am getting the below exception while processing.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
FileSource[file:///home/Teju/Desktop/SparkInputFiles/*.csv]
```

This is my code.

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "false") // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("delimiter", ":") // Specifying the delimiter of the input file
  .schema(inputdata_schema) // Specifying the schema for the input file
  .load("file:///home/Teju/Desktop/SparkInputFiles/*.csv")

val filterop = spark.sql("select tagShortID,Timestamp,ListenerShortID,rootOrgID,subOrgID,first(rssi_weightage(RSSI)) as RSSI_Weight from my_table where RSSI > -127 group by tagShortID,Timestamp,ListenerShortID,rootOrgID,subOrgID order by Timestamp ASC")
val outStream = filterop.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
```

I created cron job so every 5 mins I will get one input csv file. I am trying to parse through Spark streaming.

Comment: What's the relationship between `df` and the other datasets `filterop` and `outStream`? You don't use `df` in the code pasted. Is this on purpose? I'd say the code can't be executed as is. There's something important missing.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a solution but more a comment, but given its length it ended up here. I'm going to make it an answer eventually right after I've collected enough information for investigation).

---

My *guess* is that you're doing something incorrect on `df` that you have not included in your question.

Since the error message is about `FileSource` with the path as below and it is a streaming dataset that must be `df` that's in play.

> FileSource[file:///home/Teju/Desktop/SparkInputFiles/*.csv]

Given the other lines I *guess* that you register the streaming dataset as a temporary table (i.e. `my_table`) that you then use in `spark.sql` to execute SQL and `writeStream` to the console.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
```

If that's correct, the code you've included in the question is incomplete and does **not** show the reason for the error.

Answer (score -1):

Add `.writeStream.start` to your `df`, as the Exception is telling you.

Read the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#starting-streaming-queries) for more detail.

Comment: Where should `.writeStream.start` be added in the code pasted? I don't see how it could solve the issue. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The dataframe ```df``` never gets explicitly ```writeStream.start```ed. I suspect the query has to be "complete" without implicit/out-of-band queries closing the loop. I suspect the streamed loading of the csv is never triggered, because there is no link between input and output. I suspect that replacing ```spark.sql``` with ```df.select``` fixes this problem.